# Dropping the lowest test score

Tags: python

I'm writing a python program that drops the lowest of four test scores. The program first prompts the user to enter their first four test scores, then the program should drop the lowest test score and take the average of the remaining three test scores. The program should then print the final letter grade. This is what I have so far and I keep receiving an error when dropping the lowest score.

```
#Enter four test scores as percentages (%)
test1 = int(input("Enter grade 1: 90"))
test2 = int(input("Enter grade 2: 80"))
test3 = int(input("Enter grade 2: 70)")
test4 = int(input("Enter grade 2: 80)")

#Drop lowest test score
    print("The average, with the lowest score dropped" )
    total =(test1 + test2 + test3)

#Calculate average
        def calc_average(total):
        return total /3


#Grade scale
def determine_score(grade):
    if score >= 90:
        grade = "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        grade = "B"
    elif score >=70:
        grade = "C"
    elif score >= 60:
        grade = "D"
    else:
        grade = "F"

#Calculate final letter grade
print("The final grade is")


main()
```

Comment: Ummm... you realize that spaces/tabs are *very* significant in Python, right?

Comment: This is my first coding class so I'm still learning. Ill take any constructive criticism and advise!!

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to write a program with the things that I understood from you.
Here is the explanation:

Taking four grades from user.
Dropping the lowest one.
Taking average.
Giving a letter grade according to the average.

Here is the code:

```
test1 = int(input("Enter grade 1: "))
test2 = int(input("Enter grade 2: "))
test3 = int(input("Enter grade 3: "))
test4 = int(input("Enter grade 4: "))

x = min(test1,test2,test3,test4)

total = float(test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 - x)

avg = total / 3

print("Your average is " + str(avg))


def determine_letter(grade):
    letter =""
    if grade >= 90:
        letter = "A"
    elif grade >= 80:
        letter = "B"
    elif grade >= 70:
        letter = "C"
    elif grade >= 60:
        letter = "D"
    else:
        letter = "F"

    print("The final letter grade is " + letter)


determine_letter(avg)
```

Comment: you're welcome. You can learn more from here about Python. 
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/home/